# if $v\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then $\Delta v \in W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

if $v\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then $\Delta v \in W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$

Here $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $ W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$

and $  W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$ is dual space of the $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$

what is mean $\Delta v \in W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$

what we have to prove can some one explain me

Comment: What is the definition of $W^{-1, p'}$? It should be some dual space, but you should write the definition you have here.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro.. i wrote the definition

Comment: Are you sure about the exponent? I may be mistaken, but I think it should be $\Delta v\in W^{-1,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @MaoWao....no im correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v \in W_0^{1,p}$. We have to show $\Delta v \in W^{-1,p'}$.

$$\|\Delta v\|_{W^{-1,p'}} =\sup_{\|\phi\|_{W_0^{1,p'}} \leq 1} |\langle \Delta v ,\phi \rangle| = \sup\left|\int \nabla v\nabla \phi \,dx\right| \leq \sup |\nabla v|_{L^p} |\nabla \phi|_{L^{p'}} \leq |v|_{W^{1,p}}. $$

Comment: The space $W^{-1,p'}$ is the dual of $W^{1,p}_0$, not $W^{1,p'}_0$ (see also my comment to the OP).